# How to extend type that accepts generic elements of array?

Tags: swift, generics, swift2, swift-extensions

I have a type that I'm trying to specifically extend: `AnyObserver<[MyModel]>`. It would be easy to extend if I wasn't passing in an an array as the `Element`, which I can do something like this:

```
extension AnyObserver where Element: MyModel {...}
```

However, actually `Element` is an array, so I tried to do something like either of the below:

```
extension AnyObserver where Element: Array<MyModel> {...}
extension AnyObserver where Element: Array<T: MyModel> {...}
extension AnyObserver where Element == Array<MyModel> {...}
extension AnyObserver where Element == [MyModel] {...}
```

These result in compile errors such as:

```
Same-type requirement makes generic parameter non-generic
Type 'Element' constrained to non-protocol type
```

What is the correct way create an extension for this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you cannot extend a generic type based on a specific type parameter. You can only extend based on a protocol. But in your particular case, that gives us an out. Just don't require an Array. Require a CollectionType.

```
extension AnyObserver
    where Element: CollectionType, Element.Generator.Element == MyModel {
}
```